Unable to expose grpcs service (a hyperledger fabric peer) through ingress in a kubernetes cluster
fabric

I'm trying to deploy hyperledger fabric network in kubernetes, following the scheme in figure below. I have exposed orderer admin service (https port) and successfully accessed it through ingress, but not peer general service (via a grpcs port).
First, i deployed ingress-nginx-controller.
kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx

NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.96.65.166    <pending>     80:31345/TCP,443:31966/TCP   124m
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.99.250.161   <none>        443/TCP                      124m

Then i configured the ingress resouce. The service port number have been checked and in this case, ssl traffic should be terminated by backend service and enable-ssl-passthrough is also added in the nginx-controller cmd arg.
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: orderer0-dummy-com
  namespace: dummy-com
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0" # no limit
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true" # orderer should teminate the ssl traffic
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "GRPCS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-http2: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: orderer0.dummy.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: orderer0-dummy-com
                port:
                  name: admin
    - host: operations.orderer0.dummy.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /healthz
            pathType: Exact
            backend:
              service:
                name: orderer0-dummy-com
                port:
                  name: operations
    - host: peer0.org1.dummy.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: peer0-org1-dummy-com
                port:
                  name: listen
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: peer0-org1-dummy-com
      port:
        name: listen
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - orderer0.dummy.com

When accessing orderer0.dummy.com, the https service returned successfully, but when accessing peer0.org1.dummy.com
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.dummy.com:31966
../fabric-samples/bin/peer channel list

returned

Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer0.org1.dummy.com:31966: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded

ingress-nginx-controller side log of verbose level 4 shows the request is directed to the pod IP, but the port number turned to be 0, which should be 7051 by my config.
I1229 05:53:51.511262       7 tcp.go:74] "TLS Client Hello" host="peer0.org1.dummy.com"
I1229 05:53:51.511279       7 tcp.go:84] "passing to" hostport="10.97.233.57:0"


Pay attention, orderer0.dummy.com and peer0.org1.dummy.com have the same path, but point to different backends.

@Saxon isn't forwarding rule matches host first then matches path?  do you mean there is collision because of same path
